# How to retrieve specified fields from Entity

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, rest

I am consuming data from this api: https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers/random.
So I have to retrieve only few fields from this json: id, name, description and mesh_temp

```
{
"id": 1,
"name": "Buzz",
"tagline": "A Real Bitter Experience.",
"first_brewed": "09/2007",
"description": "A light, crisp and bitter IPA brewed with English and American hops. A small batch brewed only once.",
"image_url": "https://images.punkapi.com/v2/keg.png",
"abv": 4.5,
"ibu": 60,
"target_fg": 1010,
"target_og": 1044,
"ebc": 20,
"srm": 10,
"ph": 4.4,
"attenuation_level": 75,
"volume": {
    "value": 20,
    "unit": "litres"
},
"boil_volume": {
    "value": 25,
    "unit": "litres"
},
"method": {
    "mash_temp": [
        {
            "temp": {
                "value": 64,
                "unit": "celsius"
            },
            "duration": 75
        }
    ],
    "fermentation": {
        "temp": {
            "value": 19,
            "unit": "celsius"
        }
    },
    "twist": null
}
```

I managed to return: id, name and description

This is the logic from service that I used to get beer from api and save to database:

```
ResponseEntity<Beer[]> response = restTemplate.getForEntity("https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers/random", Beer[].class);

Beer[] beers = response.getBody();

for (int i=0; i<beers.length; i++) {
   beerRepository.save(beers[i]);
}
```

- My Entities:

  - Beer class: [Beer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Drjfw.png)
  - Method class: [Method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcJwL.png)
  - MashTemp class: [MashTemp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRdHv.png)
  - Temp class: [Temp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6iVg.png)
- I am having problem with mapping all of these, what type of relationships should I use and how to return to user only next fields: id, name, description and mesh_temp

Comment: Please add the code to the question instead of linking images. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking into your code, it seems to me that you are missing `@JsonProperty("mash_temp")` as in:

```
public class Method {

   @JsonProperty("mash_temp")
   private List<MashTemp> mash_temp = null;

}
```

Additionally, try to avoid setting collections to `null` unless you have a very good reason to do so and set them as empty. `NullPointerExceptions` will most likely decrease in frequency.

Answer (score 0):

By looking your example json it looks like one beer can have multiple mesh_temp in method.
Hence one to many relation would solve your problem. One beer can have multiple mesh_temp.